# Jointjs trigger action when hovering a markup selector of cell

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I know that it's pretty easy to trigger an action in JointJS if you click a markup selector. We can simply add a custom event attr of that markup element, but as far as I know only pointer events are allowed. Is there any way to archive the same for hovering?

For example I have a custom cell with 4 buttons, that are just a bunch of svg tag added via the markup. I want to change the opacity of all other elements on the canvas, depending on the button that was hovered. I have an idea on how to filter everything and change the opacity, but I have no idea on how to trigger that event and know what selector I'm hovering.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the `'element:mouseenter'` event on the paper, then `event.target` can give you access to sub-elements on the shape.

In the following example, when you hover a color on the button shape, the `standard.Rectangle` type shapes all change to that color.

This solution takes advantage of adding classes via `markup`, and checking if the target has the particular class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/3.6.5/joint.css" />
    <style>
        .joint-paper {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- content -->
    <div id="myholder"></div>

    <!-- dependencies -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.4.1/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/3.6.5/joint.js"></script>

    <!-- code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var namespace = joint.shapes;

        var graph = new joint.dia.Graph({}, { cellNamespace: namespace });

        var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
            el: document.getElementById('myholder'),
            model: graph,
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            gridSize: 1,
            cellViewNamespace: namespace
        });

        class ButtonShape extends joint.dia.Element {

            defaults() {
                return {
                    ...super.defaults,
                    type: 'MyShape',
                    size: {
                        width: 120,
                        height: 155
                    },
                    attrs: {
                        body: {
                            width: 'calc(w)',
                            height: 'calc(h)',
                            fill: '#ffffff',
                            stroke: '#333333',
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            rx: 5,
                            ry: 5,
                            pointerEvents: 'none'
                        },
                        rectUpper: {
                            width: 'calc(0.8*w)',
                            height: 'calc(h/2.5)',
                            fill: 'cornflowerblue',
                            stroke: '#333333',
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            x: 'calc(0.1*w)',
                            y: 10
                        },
                        rectLower: {
                            width: 'calc(0.8*w)',
                            height: 'calc(h/2.5)',
                            fill: 'tomato',
                            stroke: '#333333',
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            x: 'calc(0.1*w)',
                            y: 'calc(h - calc(h/2.5 + 10))'
                        },
                    }
                };
            }

            preinitialize() {
                this.markup = [{
                    tagName: 'rect',
                    selector: 'body'
                }, {
                    tagName: 'rect',
                    selector: 'rectUpper',
                    className: 'upper'
                }, {
                    tagName: 'rect',
                    selector: 'rectLower',
                    className: 'lower'
                }];
            }
        }

        const buttonShape = new ButtonShape();
        buttonShape.position(10, 10);
        buttonShape.addTo(graph);

        for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            const rect = new joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle();
            rect.position(i * 60 + 10, 200);
            rect.resize(50, 50);
            rect.addTo(graph);
        }
        
        paper.on('element:mouseenter', function (cellView, evt) {
            const rectangles = graph.getElements().filter((el) => el.get('type') === 'standard.Rectangle');

            if (evt.target.classList.contains('upper')) {
                rectangles.forEach((rect) => {
                    rect.attr('body/fill', 'cornflowerblue')
                });
            } 
            
            if (evt.target.classList.contains('lower')) {
                rectangles.forEach((rect) => {
                    rect.attr('body/fill', 'tomato')
                });
            } 

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```